# Install RMariaDB on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: r, ubuntu-18.04, mariadb-connector-c

On Ubuntu 18.04 R-server

```
install.packages("RMariaDB")
```

compiles ok and then it fails with

```
g++ -shared -L/usr/lib/R/lib -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -o 
RMariaDB.so DbConnection.o DbResult.o MariaBinding.o MariaResultImpl.o 
MariaResultPrep.o MariaResultSimple.o MariaRow.o MariaTypes.o MariaUtils.o 
RcppExports.o connection.o driver.o result.o -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ - 
lmariadb -lz -ldl -lm -lpthread -lssl -lcrypto -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lssl
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcrypto
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
/usr/share/R/share/make/shlib.mk:6: recipe for target 'RMariaDB.so' failed
```

What do I miss to do?

Comment: I'd say the errors are fairly clear: you need to install two libraries in the OS, likely from `libssl-dev`. I suggest you first read the [`RMariaDB` package description](https://github.com/r-dbi/RMariaDB/blob/9f88fb6ffbd2f51a37b762247871e228ef96ebec/DESCRIPTION#L41-43) which states the package requirements.

Comment: And now I fixed it myself by
    sudo apt install libssl1.0-dev